# Merging multiple PDF's with Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf, pdf-generation

I have a similar problem to this issue: [Merging 2 pdf with Zend Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254218/merging-2-pdf-with-zend-framework/8983672)

I cannot merge to pdf's together using the Zend framework.

The error message:

"Undefined property: Zend_Pdf_Element_Array::$value"

My code:

```
$pdf2show = new Zend_Pdf();
$ex = new Zend_Pdf_Resource_Extractor();
$pdf = Zend_Pdf::load('pdf1.pdf');
$pdf2show->pages[] = $ex->clonePage($pdf->pages[0]);
$pdf = Zend_Pdf::load('pdf2.pdf');
$pdf2show->pages[] = $ex->clonePage($pdf->pages[0]);
```

At this point, it doesn't matter whether I try to save the file or render the file - both will result in the same error message.

> $pdf2show->save('merged.pdf'); 
>   //not a matter of permissions, I gave the folder 777 while testing.

or

> echo $pdf2show->render();

When rendering, I use the following headers:

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="merged.pdf"');
```

I get the error message when trying to either save or render.

I am currently using Zend framework version 1.11.4 and updating it to 1.11.11 makes no difference (I have tried).
I am using php 5.3.x
I have converted my PDF's to version 1.6.

Any ideas? :-)

Comment: You converted PDF's to 1.6, but linked problem has "The static PDF must be a PDF <= 1.4 (mine was 1.6). Zend_Pdf can't parse PDF which version is > 1.4 " in answer. Why did you convert to 1.6?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4256608/707534

Comment: hmm, it seems I've read the previous posts wrong... I was sure it said to convert the PDF's to 1.6 or above... not to less than 1.4... dummy error I suppose... I will attempt with a new conversion then!

Comment: tried converting them to 1.4 now, no difference.

Comment: I think it might be my pdf's, since if I try with 2 other PDF's, that I know works, I get no errors and everything works perfectly.

Now I just gotta find out why my PDF's wont work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was the same problem, I solved it by converting the pdf to the cloned **version 1.0** with this program: http://www.freedownloadscenter.com/Multimedia_and_Graphics/Misc__Graphics_Tools/PDF_Version_Converter_Download.html

Comment: Paged linked to *automatically starts a download*. **Big time no-no in my book.**.