# Zend Framework: is it possible to combine two pdf files?

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf

I have two pages (A4).
It were converted from doc and each docuement takes up half the page A4.

So I need to combine these pages into one pdf page.

At the same time I need it to be text - not image.

Is it possible to do using Zend_Pdf?

Comment: Do you mean you have 2 pd files and want to merge them in one File ?

Comment: yes. Two half of two documents - to merge it in one file

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merging 2 pdf with Zend Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254218/merging-2-pdf-with-zend-framework)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Zend__Pdf__Resource__Extractor.

Take a look at this tutorial ->

http://theblog.enova-tech.net/2011/03/merge-two-or-more-pdf-files-in-zend-framework/

**edit

Found the same Question on Stackoverflow maybe it will help you too:
[Merging 2 pdf with Zend Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254218/merging-2-pdf-with-zend-framework)

Comment: you talk about several documents merging into one file. But if you have 2 documents then you will have one document with two pages after merging. I have 2 documents and I need get one page after merging.

Comment: Isn't this the easy part ? You just have to position them correctly on the page, using the x and y coordinates ?

Comment: I have head part and footer part and some content part. Content part can have any height. Head and footer parts are two files before merging